# Is there a reason to run exim4 on a relay?

Tags: relays

I have two relays and they both have exim4 running. Is there a reason for this? Do I have a need for a mail service running?

Comment: Running a Tor relay doesn't explicitly require exim, or any mail service, at all, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: My thoughts are to turn it off as there is no need.

Comment: Seems fine, I think some distros like debian and others end up installing exim for handling localhost mail (e.g. sending email alerts to root@localhost) so you end up with a (potentially) superfluous mail server.